# I try to send data to a localhost server unsing ajax, I can't see the correct output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I sent a simple 'hello' string to my 'index.php' file using ajax, here is the JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'index.php?value=hello',
    success: success => {
        console.log(success)
    },
    error: error => {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

and the index.php file:

```
<?php
 var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
 var_dump($_GET['value']);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <button onclick="updateValue(this)" data-value="button1">Button 1</button>
    <button onclick="updateValue(this)" data-value="button2">Button 2</button>
    <button onclick="updateValue(this)" data-value="button3">Button 3</button>
    <br>
    <p id="para">This is a test paragraph</p>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

I want to see the correct output of the var_dump($_GET['value']) in the browser, but it display NULL.
I have the correct result in the browser developer tool (Network => Response),.
Could you help me with this please ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to describe.  *"While on the browser console, i can see the correct output. In the Network session, i see the correct response."* - Those are the only two places that you ever **observe** the AJAX result.  If both of those are showing the correct result, what's the problem?  *"but it display NULL"* - **What** is displaying NULL?

Comment: Your HTML has bits missing!! You have a `</head>` but no `<head>` before it

Comment: That should work, but you could try `url: 'index.php', data{value: 'hello'},`

Comment: The Array `$_GET` only outputs, what's in the [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)-Query. Your AJAX requests again, but with an URI-Query appended. So just running the index-file always will result in an `NULL`

Comment: IF you put this in the address bar of your browser `index.php?value=hello` do you get output?

Comment: @David: the output of the var_dump() in the browser. When i console.log, i can see that it  is correct.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Yes when i directly put **index.php?value=hello** in the browser i get the correct output.

Comment: @SEFDINENASSUF: You seem to be confusing two entirely different things.  The *only thing* that your code does with the AJAX response is log it to the console.  It doesn't output *anything* to the page.  What you're seeing on the page is what was output when you first loaded the page, before making the AJAX request.  You may find it less confusing if you separated these concerns into two different PHP scripts.  One is the page, the other handles only the AJAX request and returns only that response.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: i alredy tried it, i also did a post method but it was the same result. My real goal is to listen to an event. When user click on a button the javascript will take the value of that button and sent it to php using ajax method (note: i already tried other method: axios, fetch, XMLHttpRequest) same result, i wanted to update a session on php by that value. So now i just want to send a simple string just to understand how it works

Comment: @David: Thank you for your feedback, I created another php file that just handle the AJAX request and i var_dump on that page but it still showing null, also i put the value on a session so that would display the value even if the page was refreshing, I changed the javascript code to change a paragraph if the ajax response was successed and it changed correctly. but the $_GET['value'] is still null. I don't know if i have to configure my php.ini or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working just fine.  What's incorrect is your expectation that the page will automatically update itself with the data you receive from an AJAX response.  It doesn't.

The *only thing* you're doing with the AJAX response is this:

```
console.log(success)
```

This changes absolutely nothing on the page.  What you're seeing on the page is what was included in the entirety of the page when you *first loaded* the page.  As a test, take out the AJAX operation entirely and observe that you still see the same result on the page.  (The only thing you won't see is the only thing you do with the AJAX response, the `console.log` operation.)

Overall you'll likely find this less confusing if you separate your concerns.  Create *two* PHP scripts.  One is the page itself, the other handles the AJAX request.  For example:

Let's call this `index.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <button onclick="updateValue(this)" data-value="button1">Button 1</button>
    <button onclick="updateValue(this)" data-value="button2">Button 2</button>
    <button onclick="updateValue(this)" data-value="button3">Button 3</button>
    <br>
    <p id="para">This is a test paragraph</p>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

And let's call this `ajax.php`:

```
<?php
 var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
 var_dump($_GET['value']);
?>
```

Then direct your AJAX request to the new PHP script:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'ajax.php?value=hello',
    success: success => {
        console.log(success)
    },
    error: error => {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

Now you'd observe that the page contains only the page content, and the AJAX result is logged to the console.  Basically, at this point you'd be observing that your code always worked.  You were just mixing concerns.

From there you can start to research and implement a variety of things.  Including but not limited to:

1. Update your page's markup to include a place for the output *within the markup*, not just prepended to the document before even the `DOCTYPE`.
2. Updating the page with the result from the AJAX.  You're currently using jQuery, which offers easy ways to set the text or HTML of an element on the page.
3. Returning JSON instead of plain text.  As data gets more involved, you'll find that a structured format like JSON is much easier to use than just var-dumping data to the output.